# Spark metrics: Is there a way to add some json content at a configurable interval to spark metrics

Tags: csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming, metrics, codahale-metrics

I am using spark metrics feature in my spark streaming application i am already adding two custom metric to spark metric system those are

1. Incoming Events per second : using Spark Meter
2. Number events successfully processed: using Spark counter

The above metrics are written to CSV file by spark metric system as per configuration is metrics.properties

Now my requirement is to add a json String at specified interval to spark metrics system.

The output i am expecting is CSV file which will have data some thing like below

1,jsonString1

2,jsonString2

or

jsonString1

jsonString2

Please suggest a way to do this i searched a lot but could not get the answer i am expecting

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above said requirement can be achieved using Spark Gauge.

Initialize SparkGuage object

```
com.huawei.ccloud.cloudyaf.spark.SparkGauge sparkGauge = org.apache.spark.groupon.metrics.UserMetricsSystem.gauge("samplejsonStringGauge");
```

can execute below code when each time you need to record a json string to spark metrics

```
sparkGauge.gauge("{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A green door\",\"price\":12.5,\"tags\":[\"home\",\"green\"]}");
```

The rest is taken care by Spark metric system based on configurations in metrics.properties